# Making SwiftUI shadows not bleed in sibling views

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI shadows are overlapping into other inner sibling views:

[image: shadows overlapping]

Is there a way to fix this and get a proper shadow in that case?

Example view:

```swift
// SwiftUIPlayground
// https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/

import SwiftUI

struct ShadowsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(self.scrollView, alignment: .bottom)
    }

    var scrollView: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1 ... 3, id: \.self) { _ in
                Color.white
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 30, x: 0, y: 0)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 200, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.compositingGroup()` and then apply the shadow.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/compositinggroup()) states:

> A compositing group makes compositing effects in this view’s ancestor views, such as opacity and the blend mode, take effect before this view is rendered.

This means that the views are all composited together with the shadows done separately, rather than the shadow being effected by the views underneath it.

Code:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(1 ... 3, id: \.self) { _ in
        Color.white
            .frame(height: 100)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            // .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 30, x: 0, y: 0)  // <- REMOVED
    }
}
.compositingGroup()  // <- ADDED
.shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 30, x: 0, y: 0)  // <- ADDED
.padding()
.frame(height: 200, alignment: .top)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks George, that works great! I wonder if .drawingGroup() or .compositingGroup() is faster though...

Comment: @RalfEbert Good point! I don't find them much different, but I tested it multiple times: `.drawingGroup()` took about 7.9 seconds for 100 views. On the other hand, `.compositingGroup()` took 7.3 seconds for 100 views. For the same result, I would say it would be better to actually use `.compositingGroup()` instead.

Comment: This does not work if I want to apply a different color shadow to each subview.

Answer (score 0):

If you need each subview to have a different color shadow, using `.compositingGroup()` does not work. Instead, you can add empty shadow views to a ZStack, and then add the actual views on top of them.